# Searching object

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I want to search object inside arraylist get value from user input and print it to text area. here is the code.

```
//the arrayList I declared
  Book[]myBook = new Book [30];
  int index = 0;

private void searchBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String title = titleTF.getText();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (myBook[i].getTitle().equals(title));
        {
            outputTA.append("Book Title : " + myBook[i].getTitle() + "\n");
            outputTA.append("Book Author : " + myBook[i].getAuthor() + "\n");
            outputTA.append("Year of Publication : " + myBook[i].getYear() + "\n");
            outputTA.append("Book Status : " + myBook[i].getStatus() + "\n");
            outputTA.append("======================================\n");
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found == false) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Book is not Found! Please Try again!");
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I click the search button, it will display the first object in the arraylist. Which line of code is wrong?

Comment: index is 0, do you change it somewhere?

Comment: yes, it changes after the user add the book.

Comment: An array is not an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your index is 0 so your `for` doesn't loop. Replace index with `myBook.size()`

Comment: oh my God. thanks a lot. i didnt check it. now it fix. Lol. :p